# How to add an incoming landline call to an internet conference call?

Tags: meetings, zoom

Consider this scenario:
I'm in an ongoing conference call using internet. (this conference call can be held on any suggested software like skype, google meet, zoom, etc etc)

Someone calls me from a landline.

I want to add this landline call to my conference call.

Do you know any software, any solution, any workaround for this?

Please note that I can't call this third person anyhow. It's just an incoming call from a landline.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: On which device/platform do you get that landline call?

Comment: @YisroelTech I get the landline call on iPhone/Android smart phone

Comment: Okay, so no option to forward the call from there (like you would have with business phone lines, like VoIP)

Comment: @YisroelTech Do you have any suggestions? e.g. If I get landline call on some other devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on the fact that those conferencing solutions (Skype, Teams, Meet, Zoom, and the like) have dial in numbers that people can call in (but it might depend on the plan you are on) what you should be able to do is somehow get that landline caller connected to that call-in number.

If the landline call was coming in to a VoIP system phone (business phone/extension/soft phone) you would be able to initiate a Call Transfer (Attended Transfer) whereby you would dial the call in number and access code and then transfer (hand over) the caller to that call.

If you get the call on a regular phone line (landline or mobile, where you do not have a Transfer option) the only way would be to do a 3-way-call (local conference/Add Call) on your phone to add the conference system's dial-in number to the call between you and the landline caller. (But this will keep the call on your phone the whole time as well.)